# Github workflow does not upload artifact

Tags: c++, github, github-actions, sdl-2

like the title describes, I am facing problems to upload artifacts using GitHub workflows.

the problem is:

> Warning: No files were found with the provided path: bin. No artifacts will be uploaded.

at first I thought the files were not being created due some error on compile task, so to make sure the files were there I added a ls -al to see the files and they are there,
I don't know what I am missing here.

the flow :
https://github.com/HudsonSchumaker/code-the-classics/runs/5850342583?check_suite_focus=true

Any ideas ?
Best Regards

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducer instead of linking to a repository: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How I can do that ? actions runs on GitHub

Comment: Did you try using just `bin` instead of `./bin/` for the upload action path?

Comment: @Hudson Schumaker, please share a minimal YAML that reproduces your problem. Sharing links is discouraged since they won't help people in the future and their contents not searchable on SO.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I tried all combinations possible to the path

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug `actions/upload-artifact` - looking at their [source code](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/blob/58518184d2dfe60a9c84c3dcff40cf853fdadeca/src/search.ts#L102-L122), they have it documented nicely and you should be able to pinpoint the problem.

Allow debugging by [adding a secret to your repository](https://github.com/HudsonSchumaker/code-the-classics/settings/secrets/actions/new):

name: **ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG**

value: **true**

And then run the workflow again

Comment: I putted a step with a pwd, to see the full path, used the full path and worked. is not ideal, but for now I can build.